# Генераторы тестовых данных для БД

Tags: c#, база-данных

Всем привет.

Существуют ли бесплатные библиотеки для **C#**, позволяющие нагенерировать тестовые данные согласно заданным условиям. Видел платные решения, но хотелось бы найти что-то бесплатное. )

Другими словами, есть БД, которую я хочу набить некоторыми тестовыми данными (для выполнения определённого тестирования не ней), причем данные **должны быть осмысленными и не дублироваться**. Набивать все ручками - долго и нереально, т.к. данных должно быть много. Поэтому хочу все это дело автоматизировать.

Comment: Написать скрипты с помощью C# :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://generatedata.com

Если 100 записей мало, можно скачать и поставить локально. Генерит в туче самых разных форматах, в т.ч. и sql.

Comment: Спасибо, это, конечно, не совсем то, что искал, но все равно спасибо ))